# What does "Lohn und Steuern eintragen" mean?

Tags: meaning

"Lohn" mean salary and "Steuer" mean tax.
However "eintragen" has a lot of meanings: to register, to enter, to enrol, to book, to fill in, ...
What does eintragen mean in this context?

Comment: Which context ?!?

Comment: I don't see any context at all either

Comment: Doesn't make much sense to me. Where did you see it? In a form you could fill in (eintragen) your Lohn, but filling in the tax is a bit strange. Perhaps it should be *Steuerklasse*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The various meanings of "register," "enroll," "book," for "eintragen" all seem to be correct.

In America, when employers pay their employees, there is a "gross" salary (the stated salary) that includes taxes, and the "net" salary, which is after taxes. The company is supposed to pay the employee only the "net salary," while withholding (and remitting) the taxes to the government. In any event, the company has to "book" the whole gross salaries as expenses, even while separating the two "streams" into taxes (Steuer) and (net) wages (Lohn).

In some other countries, perhaps employees receive their salaries "net" and the company also pays the employees' taxes to the government. But in this event they still have to report (register) both salaries and taxes with the government, so that the government can compare the two.

Put another way, "Lohn and Steuer" are two sides of the same coin that both have to be "booked" and "registered."

Comment: I agree that the most likely use of this phrase is in bookkeeping. But I wonder whether these specific words (Lohn/Steuern) would normallly be used in combination or rather more specific words like Abzüge...

Comment: @user1583209: That's a different discussion. I only tried to answer the question.

Comment: You are wring with your assumption: in Germany people also only geht the net Part of their salaries, Taxes are automatically paid by the company.

Comment: @TorstenLink: I changed my description. I was unfamilar with the actual structure in Germany, but it makes sense that companies have to account for the two in tandem, that is salaries to the employees and taxes to the government, and that's why the two are linked. Maybe in Germany salaries are quoted "net" instead of gross, and the company pays taxes. In America, a salary of $100,000 is before taxes. Maybe in Germany a salary of 50,000 Euros is after taxes, and the company "grosses up" the taxes if I understand you correctly.

Comment: No its exactly the same: If you say your salary is €100.000 then this is before taxes and what you get is the net value (somewhere between €50.000 and €70.000 depending on your "Steuerklasse" )...